# Objective-C partial implementation of classes in separate files

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, class-design

I am using core data and am generating classes from my data model.

I implement custom methods in these classes, however when i regenerate i generate over the top so i end up copying and pasting a bit. What i would like to do is split my implementation files ('.m') so i can have one header file with multiple '.m' files. then i can keep my custom methods in one and not have to worry about erasing them when i regenerate. I use this technique in .NET a lot with its partial keyword. Is there anything similar in objective-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to look at [mogenerator](http://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator#readme), which takes a different approach to generating classes for entities.

Comment: Exactly what i needed, although it uses derived classes, but makes generation a breeze. thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In Objective-C you have [categories (and extensions)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html).

If your CoreData class is named `Person` your implementation could go into the category `Implementation` but note that you have to declare all your ivars in the main interface of your class.

```
// Person+Implementation.h
#import "Person.h"

@interface Person (Implementation)
- (void)myMethod;
@end


// Person+Implementation.m
#import "Person+Implementation.h"

@implementation Person (Implementation)
- (void)myMethod {
    NSLog(@"hi there");
}
@end
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html